# group by while getting the Ids of the columns that meet the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to write something like this

```
SELECT MIN(date),
       id 
   FROM test 
  WHERE t.SITE_ID=SITE_id 
  GROUP BY SITE_ID
```

but its not possible to get the `id`s after a group by call.

then I came up with this

```
SELECT t.id 
  FROM test t 
 WHERE t.date IN(SELECT MIN(date) 
                   FROM test 
                  WHERE t.SITE_ID=SITE_id 
                  GROUP BY SITE_ID)
```

this select is supposed to get me the `id`s of the test rows that have the same date as the minimum date for each site is there anyway to make it simpler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM test t1
inner join
(
   select site_id, min(date) as mdate
   from test
   GROUP BY site_id
) t2 on t1.site_id = t2.site_id and t1.date = t2.mdate
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM test t1
inner join
(
   select site_id, min(date) as mdate
   from test
   GROUP BY site_id, id
) t2 on t1.site_id = t2.site_id and t1.date = t2.mdate
```